# Adding Link To Footer PHP Copywriting Text

Tags: php, html, wordpress

First post here. I have a pretty simple problem that I can't fix. I'm trying to add a hyperlink to some text my my footer. Can anyone give some tips on making the text a clickable link? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
            <p class="mb-0"><?php printf( '&copy; %s %s', date( 'Y' ), esc_html__( 'Designed by Site. All rights reserved.', 'theme' ) ) ?></p>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace has many important roles Here in this example, I have used this special PHP function to replace URL inside text block clickable.

```
<?php

$plaintext = "https://www.stackoverflow.com<br/>";

echo url_to_clickable_link($plaintext);

function url_to_clickable_link($plaintext) {

  return preg_replace(
  '%(https?|ftp)://([-A-Z0-9-./_*?&;=#]+)%i', 
  '<a target="blank" rel="nofollow" href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $plaintext);

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how to insert this code. Where should I place it? Or should I replace the existing code with it? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This code is going to help you make clickable text block (URL) 

you can paste it with your PHP code and it'll work just fine.

Comment: please upcote my answer if this worked or give me more guidelines so i can see how i can help you out

Comment: preg_replace is not a preferred way to do string replacement in WordPress. Also you should escape your output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! This is what I ended up with:

```
<?php echo "Designed by <a href='https://example.org>example.org</a> 2022. All Rights Reserved.<br/>"; ?>
```

Comment: A correct answer has already been posted to the answer. No need to answer it again

Comment: @MattewEon It's questionable if the other answer is correct. I'd say not.